# How to show that metric space $(X,d)$ is complete

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

$(X,d)$ is a metric space with property that every closed and bounded set is compact.Now how can I show $X$ is complete? Can any one help me to give hints about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Start with a Cauchy sequence. Show you can put this in a compact set; now use the fact that metric and compact implies sequential compactness. This tells us that the Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence. Now you can show that the sequence itself converges to this limit point, showing that the original sequence you began with converges.

Since the Cauchy sequence was arbitrary, all Cauchy sequences must converge, so you are done.

Comment: i thought this method .but i was unable to  put Cauchy sequence into some closed and bounded set.also Boundedness of Cauchy is obvious.can i start closure of Cauchy sequence

Comment: @AnindyaGhatak: I wouldn't say the closure of the Cauchy sequence. If you know it is bounded, then you can add $\varepsilon>0$ and consider a closed ball around some point.

Comment: @Anindya : You can take the closure of the set of the values the Cauchy sequence takes. Fix an $\varepsilon > 0$ and there exists some $N$ such that $d(x_n,X_{N+1}) < \varepsilon$ for every $n > N$, so if $y_n$ converges in your closure, the limit either takes its values in the first $N$ terms of the sequence or  it's at distance at most $\varepsilon$ of $x_{N+1}$, so the sequence is bounded. But this argument is too long pointlessly, because then you realize you can just take a closed ball around $x_{N+1}$ that's large enough and it works.